# SQL developer error i/o network adapter: not found a tns

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to install SQL developer (19.4.0), but when I create my first DB on windows 10, it shows me: error i/o the network adapter could not establish the connection.
I looked something on google, but every solution needs to access to app folder (C:/app/Username/...)
I downloaded the zip file from the official site and it doesn't install anything, just unzip and I can run SQL developer. I don't have any listener.ora or tnslistener.ora file.
I downloaded the version without java because I've already installed jdk 1.8
LINK: https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-downloads.html
What can I do?

Comment: You need a database. SQL Developer is just a client.

Comment: https://medium.com/oracledevs/i-installed-oracle-sql-developer-now-what-71230b9c9303